# Efficient way of downloading a zip file, unzip and delete it safely

Tags: zip, unzip

I am writing a small program which can download stock market information. Below is the code:

```
Dim DLink As String = "https://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/" & strThisYear & "/" & txtMonth & "/cm" & strDate & "bhav.csv.zip"

Dim SaveDir As String = GetLocation()
Dim strFile As String = SaveDir & "\Bhavcopy\" & strDate & "bhav.csv.zip"
Dim webClient As New WebClient()
webClient.Headers(HttpRequestHeader.Accept) = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,/;q=0.8"
webClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, Like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31")

webClient.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri(DLink), strFile)
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500) ' Using Thread.sleep to give time for writing. Else, the next operation fails with error 'File in Use'

Dim myFile As New FileInfo(SaveDir & "\Bhavcopy\" & strDate & "bhav.csv.zip")
Dim sizeInBytes As Long = myFile.Length

If myFile.Exists = True And myFile.Length > 0 Then ' Checking file size>0 then only unzip
    System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(myFile.ToString, SaveDir & "\Bhavcopy\")
End If

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500) ' again thread.sleep used for unzipping operation..else file in use error appears
If myFile.Exists = True Then
    Try
        myFile.Delete()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End If
```

I believe this is not efficient since I am using Thread.Sleep a few times in order to overcome 'File in Use' error. I have adjusted the sleep time from `2000ms to 500 ms` but sometimes it still gives an error.

Checking the `filesize > 0` is to check the fact that the download can be a holiday or weekend when there exists no data on that day.

Is there a better way to convert this code to efficiently download the zip file, check for `file size > 0`, then unzip it and then safely delete it?

Answer (score 0):

```
       Dim saveAs as string="C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\google.zip"
        Dim theResponse As HttpWebResponse
        Dim theRequest As HttpWebRequest
        Try 'Checks if the file exist
            theRequest = WebRequest.Create(fileUrl) 'fileUrl is your zip url
            theResponse = theRequest.GetResponse
        Catch ex As Exception
        'could not be found on the server (network delay maybe)
        Exit sub 'Exit sub or function, because if not found can't be downloaded
        End Try
        Dim length As Long = theResponse.ContentLength
        Dim writeStream As New IO.FileStream(saveAs, IO.FileMode.Create)
        Dim nRead As Integer
        Do
            Dim readBytes(4095) As Byte
            Dim bytesread As Integer = theResponse.GetResponseStream.Read(readBytes, 0, 4096)
            nRead += bytesread
            If bytesread = 0 Then Exit Do
            writeStream.Write(readBytes, 0, bytesread)
        Loop
        theResponse.GetResponseStream.Close()
        writeStream.Close()
        'File downloaded 100%
```

This code snippet too came stackoverflow but I forgot to note down the original post URL. Thanks for that code.

With this, the files are downloaded, I added code to unzip, no file lock occurs